# On the Interpretation of Point in Geometry

Tags: geometry, unit-of-measure

It is said that the point is 0 dimensional and essentially defines a location. Now, ***what is the size of the location it represents?*** What I mean is what is the size of the location characterized as X point?

I know I am confusing the abstract with the physical world but I cannot seem to solve this misinterpretation. ***Could anyone please tell me the correct interpretation of a point in the mathematical sense?***

Moving on, it is said that a line can be thought of as a collection of points, but if the points themselves are of 0 lengths, then ***how can a collection of points be of any length?***

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["How can points that have length zero result in a line segment with finite length?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417029/409), ["If point is zero-dimensional, how can it form a finite one dimensional line?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1083841/409). A site search will likely yield others.

Comment: The length of a line segment does not come from adding up the "lengths" of the points on it. It cannot. The length must come from somewhere else. That is pointed out in various ways in the better answers to the other questions.

Comment: This is actually a question of philosophy ( of mathematics ). Read [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics), [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom) and [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_geometry)